# FormAuthentication .ASPXAUTH cookie showing null after few moments in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented FormAuthentication in asp.net mvc 5 and create FormsAuthenticationticket on LogIn and it creates successfully but after few moments that cookie is showing in browser but in application it's getting null.

Please help to solve this issue.

Any help will be appreciated Thanks

LOGIN FORM

```
  public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include = "Username, Password")] LoginModel loginModel, string ReturnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Egov_Users eGov_Users = db.Egov_Users
                .Where(p => p.UserType.Type != "O" && p.UserName == loginModel.Username)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (eGov_Users == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username");
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                if (eGov_Users.Password != loginModel.Password)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Password");
                    return View();
                }

                var loginDetail = new LoginDetails();
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                loginDetail.userID = eGov_Users.UserId;
                loginDetail.username = eGov_Users.UserName;
                loginDetail.firstName = eGov_Users.FirstName;
                loginDetail.lastName = eGov_Users.LastName;

                var userData = SerializeUserInfoInternal(loginDetail);

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginDetail.username, false);

                var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(
                           FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, false);

                var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

                var durationInHours = 8;
                FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                    ticket.Version,
                    loginDetail.username,
                    DateTime.Now,
                      DateTime.Now.AddHours(durationInHours),
                    true,
                    userData);

                // Encrypt the ticket.
                string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);

                cookie.Value = encTicket;
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                int cookieSize = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(cookie.Values.ToString());
                Session["CookieSize"] = cookieSize;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
    }
```

**GLOBAL ASAX**

```
 protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
    {
        var ticket = GetTicketFromCurrentCookie();
        if (ticket == null)
        {
            Global.WriteLog("Application_PostAuthenticateRequest", "ticket becomes null");
            return;
        }
        var user = DeserializeUserInfoInternal(ticket.Name, ticket.UserData);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var principal = new AppUserPrincipal(user);
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    }
    private static FormsAuthenticationTicket GetTicketFromCurrentCookie()
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (cookie == null)
        {
            Global.WriteLog("GetTicketFromCurrentCookie", "Cookie becomes null");
            return null;
        }

        var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
        return ticket;
    }
    static LoginDetails DeserializeUserInfoInternal(string name, string userData)
    {
        var deserialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var loginDetails = deserialize.Deserialize<LoginDetails>(userData);

        return loginDetails;
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code in the question, not in the image.

Comment: var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, false);
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
var durationInHours = 8;
FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
ticket.Version,loginDetail.username,DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddHours(durationInHours),true,userData);string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
                   
                    cookie.Value = encTicket;
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas Your code needs to be *in the question*. Not posted as a commented.

Comment: I put the code in post now. Please check and help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

use below code to get the cookie value

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(".ASPXAUTH");
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.